# Replace one URL with another

Tags: php

In PHP, replace one URL with another within a string e.g.

```
New post on the site <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/xyz1">http://stackoverflow.com/xyz1</a></p>
```

becomes:

```
New post on the site <a href="http://yahoo.com/abc1">http://yahoo.com/abc1</a></p>
```

Must work for repeating strings as above. Appreciate this is simple but struggling!

Comment: Why was this question voted down?

Comment: I didn't vote it down but it's probably because it's not very clear (look at all the different answers.)

Comment: All the "different" answers imply understanding that the question was a n00b question about text substitution,

Comment: Voted down because you just don't give anought context to anwser properly.

Answer (score 3):

```
function replace_url($text, $newurl) {
    $text = preg_replace('@(https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)@', $newurl, $text);
    return $text;
}
```

Should work.
Regex stolen from [here](http://snipplr.com/view/2371/regex-regular-expression-to-match-a-url/). This will replace all URLs in the string with the new one.

Answer (score 1):

Use [str_replace()](http://php.net/str_replace):

```
$text = str_replace('http://stackoverflow.com/xyz1', 'http://yahoo.com/abc1', $text);
```

That will replace the first URL with the second URL in $text.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
preg_replace('#(https?://)(www\.)?stackoverflow.com\b#', '\1\2yahoo.com', $text);
```

If you want to change the path after the url, add another group and use `preg_replace_callabck`.  More information in the PHP documentation.